# How to copy a mysql row record and save it with different ID in same table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, copy, crud

I am new in `php`. I have a code of web form which get the data from user and save it into `mysql` database. I have an edit button. I want that when a user click on EDIT button. Here user will have an option to create a copy of same data in same table.
[image: copy]

Someone suggest me a code. But because i am new in PHP so I can't have an idea how to apply that code?

Here is code 
[image: code]

And here is my code

Comment: are you able to fetch records from database ?

Comment: @RahulMishra yes when i click on edit button then all record is fetched from db

Comment: and when you click on Copy then all records copied to clipboard or you want to insert them in db immediatly

Comment: @RahulMishra i want to insert all record in db immediately. I want when user click on copy button data will inserted in db immediately

Comment: see my answer...i hope this could help you

Comment: @RahulMishra Look at my code and please help me. I applied your code but its not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82047/discussion-between-rahulmishra-and-sunny).

Comment: what happens when you run this code...and in top of the page declare all variables as i did in my post..so that you don't need to fetch them again..

Comment: please try one thing...use same code and just change the button type of you copy to submit

Comment: @RahulMishra i changed button type to submit. nothing is happened :(

Comment: @RahulMishra m still stuck

Comment: now what...have you tried in my way or something else

Comment: @RahulMishra i tried in your way

Answer (score 1):

just store the data coming from database to global variables like:

```
<?php 
  $name  ="";
  $desgination = "";
  // and so on.....

  //fetch data from db

  $q   = mysql_query("your query");
  (while $r=mysql_fetch_array($q))
   {
     $name = $r['column_name'];
      $designation = $r['column_name'];
    //....
   }

  ?>
```

Note that your code is in same page to create copy. Now when the user presses copy button

```
  <?
   if(isset($_POST['copy']))
     {
      mysql_query("insert into table values ('$name',$designation',....)"); 
     }
```

And its done